# How can i apply my function to multiple elements?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling on applying my function to multiple elements.
What i am trying to do is have each element change individually by itself.

Only the first element is changing. I am trying to apply it to all three of them and they all should be changing separately.

For example:

Not Available

Available

Available

```js
var myVar = setInterval(breakdown, 2000);

function breakdown() {

  var d = Math.random();

  if (d < 0.90) {
    str = "Avaliable";
    text = str.fontcolor("green");
    x = true;
  } else {
    str = "Not Avaliable";
    text = str.fontcolor("red");
    y = false;
  }

  var elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.demo'));
  for (const elems1 of elems) {
    elems1.innerHTML = text;
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="demo1" class="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2" class="demo"></p>
<p id="demo3" class="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the same random value for all your elements or it has to change?

Comment: if you want to change the elements independently of each other then you need to generate a separate random number for each html element. Also remove the `break` statement inside `for loop`, that stops execution of the loop after first iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just move the generation of the random in the for loop and remove the break statement (I decresed the 0.9 to 0.5 for better evaluation)

```js
var myVar = setInterval(breakdown, 2000);

function breakdown() {

  let elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.demo'));
  for (const elems1 of elems) {
    let d = Math.random();

    if (d < 0.50) {
      let str = "Avaliable";
      text = str.fontcolor("green");
      x = true;
    } else {
      let str = "Not Avaliable";
      text = str.fontcolor("red");
      y = false;
    }
    elems1.innerHTML = text;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<p id="demo1" class="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2" class="demo"></p>
<p id="demo3" class="demo"></p>
```

Comment: this is an awesome question to solve since it includes flashy code snippets :D we should ask more questions like this

Answer (score 0):

Your "break" statement is causing the loop to end after only iterating over the first element.

Also, if you want to have each element update independently then you need to make a function to do the text generation and then call it on each element separately like in my example below.

```
var myVar = setInterval(breakdown, 1000);

function breakdown(){
    var demos = document.querySelectorAll('.demo');
  Array.from(demos).forEach(x => {
    x.innerHTML = getText();
  })
}

function getText(){
    var rand = Math.random();
  if (rand > .9) {
    return "Available";
  } else {
    return "Not Available"
  }
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle of the code working: https://jsfiddle.net/4whxv5q3/
From this you should be able to color the text or make any modifications you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Your `break` inside the loop is making it exit before it loops on all the elements. I moved the loop at the top of the function seeing your comments ('Available', 'Not available', 'Not available'). Calling the `Array.from` it isn't needed.

I would recommend other looping function, like `forEach`.

```js
var myVar = setInterval(breakdown, 2000);

function breakdown() {
 
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.demo');
  for (const elem of elems) {
  
    var d = Math.random();

    if (d < 0.90) {
      str = "Avaliable";
      text = str.fontcolor("green");
      x = true;
    } else {
      str = "Not Avaliable";
      text = str.fontcolor("red");
      y = false;
    }

    elem.innerHTML = text;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="demo1" class="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2" class="demo"></p>
<p id="demo3" class="demo"></p>
```